# Meteor method not working properly in mozilla

Tags: javascript, meteor, cross-browser

I am trying to make a call to a meteor method, to insert a document before redirecting the user to the relevant url (using the generated document _id).

The code currently ***works on chromium*** but not on firefox, where on firefox it appears to just get redirected right away without actually inserting anything.

I've attached my code at the bottom. Can anyone tell me what went wrong and what can I do to fix it? Why will chrome and firefox behave differently in this situation?

Any help provided is greatly appreciated!

## client.js

```
newDoc(){
    Meteor.call('addDoc',{
      // some parameters
    })
  }
```

## clientandserver.js (Meteor method)

```
'addDoc'(obj){
    console.log(obj); // does not output anything on firefox
    DocumentData.insert({
      //some parameters
    },function(err,documentID){
      if (Meteor.isClient){
        window.location = '/docs/' + documentID;
        // redirection happens before insertion on firefox
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: your newDoc() looks like a helper. in Blaze, helpers can get called repeatedly and unexpectedly, so a helper shouldn't do something like go to the server, or, even worse, insert a new record. you might get more inserts than you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring `window.location` to the client side. Like:

```
newDoc(){
   Meteor.call('addDoc', data, function(error, result){
     if(result){
        window.location = '/docs/' + documentID;
     }
  })
}
```

And put only the insertion in server side, like:

```
'addDoc'(obj){
    return DocumentData.insert({
      //some parameters
    });
  }
```

I've used this structure and it works for me in both Firefox & Chrome.

Comment: You are a genius!

Comment: really? I didn't though  :p